# SVG: creating 2 rectangles on the same (x, y) creates unwanted border

Tags: css, svg

```css
.rect-x {
  fill: red;
}

.rect-y {
  fill: pink;
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 1024 768">
  <rect class="rect-x" x="0" y="0" width="100" height="100"></rect>
  <rect class="rect-y" x="0" y="0" width="100" height="100"></rect>
</svg>
```

Screenshot of the issue:

[image]

why this is happen?

how can i handle it?

Comment: Please add a screenshot of the behaviour you're seeing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to turn off the antialias rendering on the `SVG`

```
svg {
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}
```

```css
.rect-x {
  fill: red;
}

.rect-y {
  fill: pink;
}

svg {
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 1024 768">
  <rect class="rect-x" x="0" y="0" width="100" height="100"></rect>
  <rect class="rect-y" x="0" y="0" width="100" height="100"></rect>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try adding `shape-rendering="crispEdges"` to disable antialiasing

```css
.rect-x {
  fill: red;
}

.rect-y {
  fill: pink;
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 1024 768">
  <rect class="rect-x" x="0" y="0" width="100" height="100"></rect>
  <rect class="rect-y" x="0" y="0" width="100" height="100"></rect>
  
  <rect class="rect-x" x="200" y="0" width="100" height="100" shape-rendering="crispEdges"></rect>
  <rect class="rect-y" x="200" y="0" width="100" height="100" shape-rendering="crispEdges"></rect>
</svg>
```